# how to get range slider value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I want to store the value that is set by the user when he uses the slider and I want to store the value in a variable, for example a user uses the price slider, and he sets the value to $1000, i want to store this value in a variable then compare it in an if else statements for example:
recommend.addEventListener("click", () => {
if(selected.textContent === "Productivity" && selected2.textContent === "1080P" && priceSetByUser> 1000)
$(model).show();
});

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "slider" id = "slide">
      <div 
    id="slider-range" style="width: 50%; left: 25%;  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #bd6077 0%, #ec7e5d 100%);">
      </div>
                  <p><label for="amount" style="color: #f6931f; position: relative; left: 45%;">Price range:
                  </label>
                    <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:none; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;left: 45%;
                    position: relative; background-color: rgb(48, 43, 43); width: 20%;"></p>
               
                    </div>
```

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 10000,
  values: [0, 100],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);

    $("#amount").change(); //add this line to trigger text change     
      
  },
  stop: function(){ // when user stops
  console.log($( "#amount" ).val())
    
}   
 
})
```

Comment: Note that the jQuery UI [project page](https://blog.jqueryui.com/2021/10/jquery-maintainers-update-and-transition-jquery-ui-as-part-of-overall-modernization-efforts/) says "jQuery UI is in maintenance-only mode. Users should not expect any new releases..." So it may not be something you want to use in a new design or spend time learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input id="slider" type="range" min="" max="" 
   step="any" value=""/>
   <script>
   var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
   slider.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
   console.log(event.target.value);
   }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var myRange = [
    0,
    0
  ];
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000,
    values: [0, 100],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
      $("#amount").change();
      myRange = ui.values;
    },
    stop: function() { // when user stops
      console.log(myRange.join(" - "));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="slider" id="slide">
  <div id="slider-range" style="width: 50%; left: 25%;  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #bd6077 0%, #ec7e5d 100%);">
  </div>
  <p><label for="amount" style="color: #f6931f; position: relative; left: 45%;">Price range:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" style="border:none; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;left: 45%; position: relative; background-color: rgb(48, 43, 43); width: 20%;"></p>
</div>
```

This defines an Array that can be used later with both Range Values.